# Making sure my application is Terminal Services safe

Tags: c#, terminal-services

Our company uses a system of which I am the sole developer. It is a C# based desktop application that is run on some 50 workstations or so and all connect to one central SQL Server database.

Our network administrator is now looking at presenting the application through Terminal Services, something that I know nothing about, yet.

As I started Googling around I saw that, apparently, some applications do not work under Terminal Services. MS Paint is mentioned as an example. So this got me wondering, what does a developer need to know to make sure that his/her application works in Terminal Services?

I don't have the time right now to investigate TS in depth but I'm hoping there might be an article somewhere that is written for developers. As in "Things not to do when you develop an application that will be run in Terminal Services".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal Service RemoteApp works pretty well if you application is designed to be multi-user compatible. so you will need to ensure user session related data is not shared, but placed in isolated storage with IsolatedStorageContainment set to DomainIsolationByUser for example.

here are some useful links:

http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/terminal-services/remoteapp.htm

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nf20-76dMcg

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. It looks like these are things that the Terminal Services administrator have to be aware of, not the developer so much.

Comment: the developer must be aware of the nature of the hosting, as the implication of having an application run multiple instaces by different users on the same server. so if you application is using the same file for different users you have to think about security and access contention.

Comment: did this help out?, can you upvote/accept my answer if so, cheers